# Class does not exist

Tags: class, laravel, view

I have Service Provider Class and this calls a View Composer Class...
But after running the program shows me this error

> Class Oims\Http\SidebarComposer does not exist

ComposerServiceProvide Class:

```
namespace Oims\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot(ViewFactory  $view)
    {
       $view->composer('layout.sidebar','Oims\Http\SidebarComposer');

    }
```

SidebarComposer Class:

```
namespace Oims\Http\SidebarComposer;

use Oims\Menus;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;


class SidebarComposer
{


    public function compose(View $view)
    {
            $menus =Menus::all();
            $view->with('menus',$menus);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right namespace should be:

```
namespace Oims\Http;

use Oims\Menus;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;


class SidebarComposer
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with fixing namespace from this:

```
namespace Oims\Http\SidebarComposer;
```

To:

```
namespace Oims\Http;
```